# IE 10: dragstart event doesn't get fired if <img> is wrapped by <a>

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39she/3/

HTML:

```html
<a href="http://google.de">
  <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo4w.png" draggable="true" />
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// Please forgive me this bad-designed function ;)
// quick and dirty solution
function log(msg) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<hr />" + msg;
}

var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

myImg.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
    log("Drag started");
});
```

The log message appears in *Chrome 27*, *Safari 5.1* and *Opera 12.15*. Only IE 10 does not fire any event (though it fires the `drop` event when the image gets dropped afterwards).

**Edit 1** 
Listening for `dragstart` at the link tag works fine in IE 10.

Comment: Encountered the same on Firefox 50.

Comment: The question for Firefox can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184362/firefox-dragstart-event-doesn-t-fire-in-hyperlink-s-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to cancel the initial text selection event as well as activate the drag functionality for it to work.

**EDIT 1:**

```
var output = document.querySelector('#message')
, myImg = document.querySelector("#test")

function log(msg) {
  output.innerHTML = msg + ' ' + (+new Date());
}

myImg.addEventListener('selectstart', function (evt) {          
  evt.preventDefault && evt.preventDefault();
  this.dragDrop && this.dragDrop();  //activates DnD for IE  
  return false;
});

myImg.addEventListener('dragstart', function (evt) { 
  log('started');
});

myImg.addEventListener('dragend', function (evt) { 
  log('ended');
});
```

Best of luck!

**Note :**
It appears it's that IE treats  tags with href attributes as draggable by default. But when you remove the href property, it works just fine. Quite interesting actually. codepen.io/snypelife/pen/hImer

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response. I'll give it a try in the next days ;)

Comment: Have a look at this.  It works for me even in IE9: http://codepen.io/snypelife/pen/pdnbv

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! But where was the actual relevant difference?

Comment: I believe it was because you we're updating the <body> with the image and log message, that the original image with the event listeners attached was being replaced by one without listeners.  Make sense?  And glad I could help you out!

Comment: Sounds absolutely reasonable, but why does this fiddle still not work? http://jsfiddle.net/39she/23/

Comment: It appears it's that IE treats <a> tags with href attributes as draggable by default.  But when you remove the href property, it works just fine.  Quite interesting actually.  http://codepen.io/snypelife/pen/hImer

Comment: Very strange but interesting! Thanks for your help, I'll give you a bounty of 300pts in 23 hours. (Could you please add your last comment to your answer, that would be very nice for other users with the same problem).