# html5: drag and drop cannot work in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

The following code from W3CSchool. If without hyperlink "a" element, the image "img" element can be dragged into the above box in Firefox and IE; however, if with the "a" element, the "img" element cannot be dragged into the above box in Firefox, but not IE. Everything works fine in Chrome. The browers's version information: Firefox(V33), IE(V10), Chrome(V37). Any ideas. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<a href="http://www.bing.com" >
    <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE 10: dragstart event doesn't get fired if <img> is wrapped by <a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750180/ie-10-dragstart-event-doesnt-get-fired-if-img-is-wrapped-by-a)